# Looking for a inBrowser WebPage Text or Content Editor

Tags: html, web-browser, html-editor

From the perspective of a regular web surfer...

I am looking for a tool that will allow me edit the content (text) of a webpage. While browsing if I find an interesting article, I usually like to "rewrite" the articles to delete irrelevant content and create rich editing of key sentences, create bullet points/numbering that I find interesting, write my own subtopics, etc. I then will use something like firefox addon "Scrapbook" to save the page. This way it is only content i want to see and reconfigured to my liking.

Imagine clicking a button for any webpage that has written content and a rich text editor toolbar appears that allows you to do editing, (just an idea)

I did find this javascript but its primitive, im looking for a richer text editing experience, (bullets, font color, numbering, etc, if possible) http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2011/03/javascript-tricks-edit-websites-in.html

I have tried looking at "mark down editors" but that doesn't allow for editing a webpage, just creating markdown in the browser. I hope i made myself clear, let me know if you came across such a tool or script....

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What browser are you using? Would you be willing to pay for such a function and if so, how much?

Comment: i can use any browser that the tool will work in.  If i get what i need I would be willing to pay for it... How much? it depends on how cool the tool is, how good it works, ease of use, etc, etc. do you have anything in mind??